# load JSON data attributes from external php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hi I try to load a JSON data from a php link in a js file whith this

> $.getJSON('link to rempl.php', function(data) {
>      cn =data.nom;
>     });

this is the code of rempl.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
require_once ('connectDB.php');
if ($_POST['nom']== 0){
header("Location: http://localhost/geopp/editer.php");
}else{
$id = $_POST['nom'];
}

$sql = "SELECT    id , id_archi ,  nom ,  archithect ,  adresse ,  date_construction ,  dateconst , resume FROM  patri where id=".$id.";";
$req = mysqli_query ($link,$sql);
$feature = array();
//echo "lon\tlat\ttitle\tdescription\ticon";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req)) {

$res['id_archi'] = $row['id_archi'];
$res['id'] = $row['id'];
$res['date'] = $row['dateconst'];
$res['nom'] = $row['nom'];
$res['archithect'] = $row['archithect'];
$res['adresse'] = $row['adresse'];
$res['date_construction'] = $row['date_construction'];
$res['resume'] = $row['resume']; 
$feature[] =  json_encode($res); 
}
echo  implode(', ',$feature); 
header("Location: http://localhost/geopp/empl.php");
?>
```

but when I alert the variable cn it show me undefined and thanks for helping me.

Comment: `echo  implode(', ',$feature);` most certainly does not produce valid JSON. You can test the validity of the response here: http://jsonlint.org/

Comment: `$.getJSON` is not going to be affected by location headers, I'd expect to see json_encode somewhere in your php

Comment: what is the point of the last header location

Comment: @andrew: Here `$feature[] =  json_encode($res);` ;)

Comment: @FelixKling O_o missed that!

Comment: I tested in jsonlint.org  it's valid